# REST call not support language in IE

Tags: rest

I am making a rest call to filter data from list which is working fine Google Chrome but not in IE. Need to support multiple language

```
/sites/Test/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Master')/items?$select=*&$filter=substringof('银行存款1',code) or substringof('银行存款1',TextZH)
```

Comment: Did you debug it on IE ? What is the error message in console ?

Comment: Debugged in IE, There is no record returned. Length of result is 0. If i try to debug in Chrome then i m getting result.

Comment: Did you find answer for this ?

Comment: @BhaskarDhone we used encodeURIComponent(uri);

Comment: I am also facing the same issue with the Arabic language, we can use "encodeURIComponent("any language filter value")" and pass this encoded value into REST api Filter condition and it worked without any issues.